# KendoUI Change filters on filter event

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a cascade filter (a child filter should display specific data based on the parent selection) on a grid. I manage to do this using custom templates. Now I have to remove the child filter when the parent filter is removed. (the parent and child fields are on the same grid)

Is there a way to influence the filtering of another field on the Filter event?

```
function onFiltering(args) {
    //var datasource = args.sender.dataSource; //=> filter is undefined
    var datasource = $(args.sender).data("kendoGrid").dataSource; // => could not found the kendo widget
    var filters = datasource.filter();
    datasource.filter([]);

    // never manage to get to this part of code
    // determine if the parent filter exist in the filters
    var result = ...

    if (result.length == 0) {
        // determine the position of the child filter in the filters
        indexes = ...
        // remove the child filter
        filters = filters.splice(indexes[0], 1);
    }
    // set the new filter
    datasource.filter(filters);
}
```

I have tried some ways to get to the dataSource and/or filter but none seems to work.

Comment: I'm a little confused, do you want to know how to apply multiple filters to the same field? Here is an [example of complex filtering](http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/MG89G/)

Comment: I want to remove a filter when another filter is cleared. Think in your example that when the Ship Name filter is removed also the Ship City should be removed also. But I need this in a consistent way so that 3 fields could be cleared in cascade.

Comment: Presumably you are building up an array of filters on the same dataSource? Providing a small [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/eNujo) would definitely help here (at least to provide more context to your question).